# Change FileStat.ctime in Elixir

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix, ctime

I intend to do sorting of files by date. To test my function I created an environment with a `Stream` with `File.Stat`s which is represented as the follwing:

```
@type t() :: %File.Stat{
  access: :read | :write | :read_write | :none,
  atime: :calendar.datetime() | integer(),
  ctime: :calendar.datetime() | integer(),
  gid: non_neg_integer(),
  inode: non_neg_integer(),
  links: non_neg_integer(),
  major_device: non_neg_integer(),
  minor_device: non_neg_integer(),
  mode: non_neg_integer(),
  mtime: :calendar.datetime() | integer(),
  size: non_neg_integer(),
  type: :device | :directory | :regular | :other | :symlink,
  uid: non_neg_integer()
}
```

I want to manipulate the ctime of those `File.Stat`s manually by code.

In my `test_file.exs` I used the `Process.sleep(1001)` command to ensure the `ctime`s will never match, unfortunately this makes my tests run very slow.

Comment: `File.Stat` is just a struct, so you can modify any field, e.g. `%{stat | ctime: {{2023, 2, 10}, {11, 55, 12}}}`.

Comment: I agree, I need to clarify my example, the stream results from a given directory tree with files and sub directories in it. So I (also) want to manipulate the file's ctime.

Comment: The touch command seems the obvious solution. % ls -l myfile.txt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 bortzmeyer bortzmeyer 29 Feb 21 17:33 myfile.txt
% touch --date 2000-01-01 myfile.txt 
% ls -l myfile.txt                  
-rw-r--r-- 1 bortzmeyer bortzmeyer 29 Jan  1  2000 myfile.txt

Comment: Please provide your function and test code so we can see what you are trying to do.